# Регулярное выражение для поиска подстроки

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Начал изучать регулярки и не могу понять, как мне задать поиск для некоей подстроки (назову ее STRING, она берется из массива), и при этом заключить ее в условие - я есть отдельное слово (фраза) ИЛИ любой символ (задается точкой в регулярках)

тобиш я допускаю варианты типа STRING (STRING) [STRING] STRING, и тому подобное и так как это название, то оно может стоять отдельно в новой строке (как заголовок чего либо) или в начале новой или в конце строки, или ее могут выделить скобками или как то еще выделить. Я сам долабаю регулярку, но я не могу понять как мне задать условие, что это ИЛИ отдельное слово \b или любой из перечисленных символов в наборе. Я пытался использовать | но что то не того... Вот как я пробовал

```
\b|.(STRING)\b|.
```

Ну и двойное экранирование тоже пробовал

```
\\b|.(STRING)\\b|.
```

Пример с которым я сейчас бьюсь выглядит так:

```
bla bla bla STRING (СТРИНГ) bla bla....
```

- в этом примере я пробегаюсь массивом и должен заменить как STRING, так и СТРИНГ указанный в скобках. Слова STRING и СТРИНГ придут из массива для проверки.

Comment: Ни чего не понял, но `(\b|\.)(STRING)(\b|\.)` что-то такое, если подразумевали и в начале, и в конце границу слова или точку.

Comment: Я не понял, чему в итоге регулярное выражение соответствовать должно, а чему нет? Было бы понятнее и вам и мне, если выписать несколько вариантоы: строка - ожидаемый результат. На них же потом хорошо тестировать выражение.

Comment: Пример с которым я сейчас бьюсь выглядит так: bla bla bla STRING (СТРИНГ) bla bla.... - в этом примере я пробегаюсь массивом и должен заменить как STRING, так и СТРИНГ указанный в скобках. Слова STRING и СТРИНГ придут из массива для проверки.

Comment: `STRING|\(СТРИНГ\)` ?

Comment: неее. регулярка будет в цикле. Ей придут варианты слов, одно будет STRING, Другое ну например перевод этого же слова СТРИНГ, и их надо заменить будет на что либо. У меня всё уже есть и работает, всё заменяется, но хочется облагородить замены. Что бы не получалось замен для "bla blastring STRING" в blastring и что бы заменялись в скобках и прочих специмволах

Comment: непонятно ничего. только целые слова чтоли ?

Comment: Вот этот ответ в общем работает (\b|\.)(STRING)(\b|\.), я просто недопёр, что надо не в квадратных перечислять а набором в круглых.

Comment: Сударь, извольте посодействовать еще лишь раз. Как бы мне вернуть в сим верном варианте (\b|\.)(STRING)(\b|\.), так же и те игривые символы, кои скрылись с моих глаз по окраинам сего выражения? Я не изволю терять их сохранив пунктуацию. Верно ли я понимаю, что вышеизложенное выражение вернет мне STRING но без обрамления? Или суть моего вопроса ускользает от меня в моей же ошибке где то в коде программы?

Comment: Ошибка крылась у меня. Сим откланиваюсь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Простой пример на основание [учебника](https://learn.javascript.ru/regular-expressions-javascript)

```js
var str = 'bla bla bla STRING STRING (СТРИНГ) bla bla.... '; 
var res = str.replace(/(\b|\.)STRING(?=\b|\.)/g, '\$1СТРИНГ');
alert(res);
```